# Calculating Weighted Average

Tags: excel

I'm trying to work on a sheet and need to calculate the weighted average based on an item code and it's corresponding weight and price, if any. The problem I'm running into is that I can't get my formula to ignore blank cells. I thought I was close on it but I still can't get it. Here's my formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E4:E407=L5),J4:J407,G4:G407)/SUMIF(J4:J407,">0",G4:G407)
```

E- is my item codes where it needs to equal L- which is one code
J- is my price where a lot of cells don't have a value in them
G- is the weight where I don't need it to read the weight if I don't have values in J

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yes unfortunately in some circumstances, Excel reads a blank cell as being >0.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using Excel's ISNUMBER function. It will return true if there is a value in the cell. See this helpful tutorial on how to use it:

http://www.exceltip.com/excel-array-formulas/ignoring-blank-cells-when-performing-calculations.html

If you'd like to know how to use it in your specific example it'd be helpful to see some sample data.

Comment: Also I just realized another problem, in my formula all of my weights are calculating, but all I need is for them to calculate for the certain codes. What could I do there?

Comment: I need you to be a little more specific. If you have some sample data and your most up to date formula I could be of much more help.

Comment: Also could try SUMIFS instead of SUMIF